# ValueError in tests permission in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, permissions, webtest

I want to test permissions in my application. I want to give my user permissions and see if they are there.
I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'myapp.can_view'
```

**CODE**

```
class PermissionsTest(WebTest):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = G(User, username='user', password='pass')

    def test_user_login_permission(self):
        app = self.app.get(reverse('myapp:dashboard'), user=self.user)
        self.assertEqual(app.status_code, 200)

    def test_user_add_permissions(self):
        self.user.user_permissions.add('myapp.can_view')
        self.user.save()
        self.assertTrue(self.user.has_perm('myapp.can_view'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.user_permissions` is a M2M field so you can't add a string to this field.  Add a `Permission` instance instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_view')
self.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Also note that permissions [are cached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching) so you have to reload `User` object in the test.

**UPDATE**: If the codename for your permission is not unique then you have to add a `content_type` to the `get()` call as in the @selcuk's answer.

**UPDATE 2**: To create a persmission you have two options.

Automatically, using the [`permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#permissions) property to your `Model.Meta` class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (('can_view', u'Can view my model'), )
```

By hand:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

ct = ContentType.objects.ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
permission = Permission.objects.create(content_type=ct,
                                       codename='can_view',
                                       name='Can view my model')
```

Comment: I get DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `permission` object to `add` method, not a string. This should help:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)
permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type, codename='can_view')
request.user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```